# paypal api adaptive payments account restricted

Tags: paypal

we have an application that allows a user to purchase images using chained payments from multiple sellers. But I keep getting an error that the accounts for the user receiving payments are restricted. We tested correctly in the sandbox, the URLS are correct in production and we can make a successful transaction with our own paypal accounts. I was under the understanding a person can make a payment to a non-paypal registered email and paypal would prompt the user to regsiter/login to paypal to receive funds. How exactly can an account restricted? Are there any workarounds to this issue besides finding an alternate payment method?

Comment: Have you asked Paypal directly? This sounds like an issue their customer support would be better able to handle.

Comment: I have asked on their forums, I could try emailing tech directly I suppose. But stack exchange usually has very good responses. I was hoping someone maybe has ran into this issue before as well, or they could verify a user doesn't have to registered with paypal to receive payments.

Comment: Pretty sure a receiver has to be registered when setting them as the receiver in Adaptive Payments; but as +cdeszag mentioned, contact support via https://www.paypal.com/dts/ to be sure.